Bibliography not working in TexStudio
It won't print my bibliography, I have the following main document
\documentclass[11pt]{paper}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}%Bibliographie
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

And my file refs.bib has the following code
@book{kelly 1,
    author = {John Kelly},
    title = {General Topology},
    date = {1955}
}
@article{Tychonoff 1,
    author = {Andrei Tychonoff},
    title = {Ein Fixpunktsatz},
    journaltitle = {Mathematische Annalen},
    date = {1935},
    OPTvolume = {111},
    OPTissue = {1},
    OPTpages = {767-776},
    OPTurl = {https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematische-annalen_1935_111/page/772/mode/2up},
    OPTurldate = {28.12.2024},
}

I read about some common issue and I checked everything: I change the bib-programm to biber in TexStudio, made sure that biber and bibtex are installed on the pc and checked if I named the files differently. Nothing.
I tried using biblatex instead and forcing TexStudio to run Bibliography which both did not work

Do you \cite anything in your real document?

Yes, it does not work but there is no error message. I didn't think it was necessary for this MME

If your MWE does not cite anything, the output is as expected. That being said, remove the spaces in your bib keys.

Remove the spaces in your bib keys:
\documentclass[11pt]{paper}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}%Bibliographie

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{refs.bib}
@book{kelly1,
    author = {John Kelly},
    title = {General Topology},
    date = {1955}
}
@article{Tychonoff1,
    author = {Andrei Tychonoff},
    title = {Ein Fixpunktsatz},
    journaltitle = {Mathematische Annalen},
    date = {1935},
    OPTvolume = {111},
    OPTissue = {1},
    OPTpages = {767-776},
    OPTurl = {https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematische-annalen_1935_111/page/772/mode/2up},
    OPTurldate = {28.12.2024},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Yes, that worked! thank you!

@TeX_User You're welcome!
